# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'insertRow' of undefined

Tags: javascript, html, forms, dom, html-table

*EDIT* TO INCLUDE ALL CODE
If I take off the tbody reference I'm back to this error
"Uncaught TypeError: regTable.insertRow is not a function at addRegistration"

I'm having trouble with this javascript method to add form data to a table.
After filling out the form information when users click on the button it should add it to the table.  I've tried a couple of solutions other people have posted here and so far none have worked. It was getting a different error message "uncaught type error: table.insertrow is not a function" but it always stops on that line. I'm worried I'm going to have the same problem when I add the delete button, which I haven't gotten to because I've been stuck here.
I'm wondering if I'm missing something really easy like a typo? This is my first class in web programming so it may be.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <title> Player Registration  </title>

        <h1>Enter Player Information</h1>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="flexbox">
        <form id="registration" action="#">
           <p> <label for="name">Name:</label>
            <input id="name" type="text" autofocus required></p>

           <p><label for="slevel">Skill level:</label></p>
           <input id="sLevel" type="text" ></p>

           <p> <label for="email">Email:</label>
            <input id="email" type="email" ></p> required></p>

           <p> <label for="city">City:</label>
            <input id="city" type="text" ></p>

           <p> <input type = "button" value = "Register" id="saveButton"> </p>
        </form>
        </div>
        <hr>
        <div>
            <table id="registration" >
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th>Name</th>
                        <th>Level</th>
                        <th>Email</th>
                        <th>City</th>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Name</td>
                        <td>Level</td>
                        <td>Email</td>
                        <td>City</td>
                    </tr>
                </tbody>
            </table> 
        </div>
    </body>
    <script>
        document.getElementById("saveButton").onclick = function() {addRegistration()};
        function addRegistration() {
                var regTable = document.getElementById("registration").getElementsByTagName('tbody')[0];
                var newRow = regTable.insertRow(-1);
                var cell1 = insertCell(0);
                var cell2 = insertCell(1);
                var cell3 = insertCell(2);
                var cell4 = insertCell(3);
                cell1.innerHTML = "name";
                cell2.innerHTML = "slevel";
                cell3.innerHTML = "email";
                cell4.innerHTML = "city";
        }
        </script>
</html>
```

Comment: You should select the table element, not tbody. Also, without more context, I can't see the registration element to know whether there's an issue with that.

Comment: No, because .getElementsByTagName('tbody') isn't creating the error

Answer (score 0):

the syntax for insertRow() is tableObject.insertRow(index);.

depending on what browser or version you're using, you might have to actually provide an index value and if so you can use "... regTable.insertRow(-1); to add it to the end.  Also add a console.log(regTable); and if it returns undefined or null then it's either not defined or is defined but has no elements(basically regTable == [ ])

Answer (score 0):

the id must be unique, and you have 2 id = "registration" in your code. this is the reason for the error.
but there are also other errors in your html, I have indicated them here.
Also pay attention to your `<p>` `</p>` tags, there must be the same number.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title> Player Registration </title>
</head>
<body>
  <h1>Enter Player Information</h1> <!-- was on a wrong place in your code -->
  <div class="flexbox">
    <form id="registration-form"> <!-- id must be unique -->
      <p> 
        <label for="name">Name:</label>
        <input name="name" type="text" autofocus required>
      </p>
      <p>
        <label for="sLevel">Skill level:</label>
         <input name="sLevel" type="text">   <!-- use name= (no id=) -->
      </p>
      <p>
        <label for="email">Email:</label>
        <input name="email" type="email" required>
      </p>
      <p>
        <label for="city">City:</label>
        <input name="city" type="text">
      </p>
      <button type="submit">Register</button>  <!-- use submit to verify required input  -->
    </form>
  </div>
  <hr>
  <div>
    <table id="registration-table">  <!-- id must be unique -->
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th>Name</th>
          <th>Level</th>
          <th>Email</th>
          <th>City</th>
        </tr><!--this one is missing in your code -->
      </thead>
      <tbody>
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </div>
  <script>
    const regForm    = document.querySelector('#registration-form')
      ,   tableTbody = document.querySelector('#registration-table tbody')
      ;
    regForm.onsubmit = evt => // when submit is complete (after inputs are verified)
      {
      evt.preventDefault()  // disable submit (and page re-load)

      let newRow = tableTbody.insertRow()

      newRow.insertCell().textContent = regForm.name.value    // note the use of the 
      newRow.insertCell().textContent = regForm.sLevel.value // `name` for the inputs
      newRow.insertCell().textContent = regForm.email.value // preceded by the 
      newRow.insertCell().textContent = regForm.city.value // reference of their form 
      regForm.reset()
      }
  </script> <!-- the script is before /body -->
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: That worked! Thank you so much now I just have to figure out how to get it to add the input from the form. It's just adding what's in the quotes and not getting the data from the fields

Comment: @KathrynMcMeen I added a complete HTML, with the insertion of the form inputs into the table.

Answer (score 0):

Your html has the same id. (form id="registration")

Change your table id.

Also there is an error in the insertCell.
Add newRow before insertCell. `newRow.insertCell(0);`

```
<body>
    <div class="flexbox">
    <form id="registration" action="#">
       <p> <label for="name">Name:</label>
        <input id="name" type="text" autofocus required></p>

       <p><label for="slevel">Skill level:</label> <input id="sLevel" type="text" ></p>

       <p> <label for="email">Email:</label> <input id="email" type="email" required></p>

       <p> <label for="city">City:</label> <input id="city" type="text" ></p>

       <p> <input type = "button" value = "Register" id="saveButton"> </p>
    </form>
    </div>
    <hr>
    <div>
        <table id="tableRegistration">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>Name</th>
                    <th>Level</th>
                    <th>Email</th>
                    <th>City</th>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <td>Name</td>
                    <td>Level</td>
                    <td>Email</td>
                    <td>City</td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table> 
    </div>
</body>
<script>
    document.getElementById('saveButton').onclick = function() {addRegistration()};
    function addRegistration() {
        var regTable = document.getElementById("tableRegistration").getElementsByTagName('tbody')[0];
        console.log(regTable);
        var newRow = regTable.insertRow(0);
        var cell1 = newRow.insertCell(0);
        var cell2 = newRow.insertCell(1);
        var cell3 = newRow.insertCell(2);
        var cell4 = newRow.insertCell(3);
        cell1.innerHTML = "name";
        cell2.innerHTML = "slevel";
        cell3.innerHTML = "email";
        cell4.innerHTML = "city";
    }
</script>
```

Comment: see my answer here,  you will learn more ;)